# $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(\sin{4x})(-\cos{x})}{x}$ without l'Hôpital's Rule?

Tags: limits, trigonometry, derivatives, limits-without-lhopital

I've thought of the sandwich theorem but can't find anything to squeeze it in !

Comment: $\lim4\frac{\sin4x}{4x}(-\cos x)=-4$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's build our way up to the answer.

**Step 1.**   Find the value of $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin 4x}{4x}$$

**Step 2.** Use the result above to find the value of $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin 4x}{x}$$

**Step 3.** Finally use the result above to find the value of $$\lim_{x\to 0} \left(\frac{\sin 4x}{x}\cdot-\cos(x)\right)$$

Can you take it from there?

Comment: Yes! It should do! Than you so much!!